# Call to undefined function in drupal Controller

Tags: php, drupal

I got a simple module that create a site using controller but it keeps telling me `Call to undefined function Drupal\example\Controller\getTickets()`.

I'm pretty new to PHP and I can't manage to fix this.

**Here's my code:**

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\example\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class Controller extends ControllerBase
{
    function getTickets(){
        $results = [];
        return $results;
    }

    public function page()
    {
        $data = [];
        $data = getTickets();
        $element = [];
        foreach ($data as $bit) {
            array_push($element, array(
                '#markup' => $bit,
            ));
        }
        return $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes this is working now. Many thanks and sorry for such a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$data = getTickets();
```

To:

```
$data = $this->getTickets();
```

;)